# xmlHTTP request error: "failed"

Tags: javascript, http, error-handling, request

```
var xmlHTTP = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHTTP.open('GET','http://example.com/',true);
xmlHTTP.send();
```

I just keep getting `XHR failed loading: GET`, can anyone help???

Thanks

Comment: does it work if you remove the third parameter, e.g. `true`?

Comment: could it be CORS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the server your contacting doesn't have CORS set in the header (e.g. access-control-allow-origin: *), you will not be able to make the request. If you don't have access to the server to set a CORS header, you'll need to contact the server from a server you do control and then pass that to the browser (either with a CORS header or not if it's served from the same domain)

But your code works fine.  The problem is with your http://example.com/ not returning

http://jsbin.com/zuhobidako/edit?html,js,console,output

```
var xmlHTTP = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHTTP.open('GET','https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',true);
xmlHTTP.send();

xmlHTTP.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.body.innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
```

For server status errors, add this to onreadystatechange

```
if( this.status > 299 && this.readyState == 4) {
    console.log('Server Error: ' + xmlHTTP.statusText);
}
```

For xmlHTTP code errors...

```
xmlHTTP.onerror = function() {
    console.log('xmlHTTP Error', xmlHTTP.responseText)
}
```